# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am getting the following error:

```java
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element(uri:"http://www.docsite.com/ClientConfig.xsd", local:"ClientConfig").
Expected elements are <{http://www.docsite.com/ClientConfig.xsd/}ClientConfig>
```

my root element class file is:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="ClientConfig",namespace="http://www.docsite.com/ClientConfig.xsd/")
public class ClientConfig {}
```

my package.info file is:

```java
@XmlSchema(namespace="http://www.docsite.com/ClientConfig.xsd",elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package com.convertXml.docSite.XmlConverter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

let me know what can I do to fix this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You have an extra / at the end of the namespace specified in the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

---

**LONG ANSWER**

**package-info**

The namespace is specified correctly in the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation:

```java
@XmlSchema(namespace="http://www.docsite.com/ClientConfig.xsd",elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.convertXml.docSite.XmlConverter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

**ClientConfig**

But you have overridden it with an incorrect namespace on the `ClientConfig` class.  You have an extra `/` at the end of the namespace specified in the `@XmlRooElement` annotation.

```java
package com.convertXml.docSite.XmlConverter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="ClientConfig",namespace="http://www.docsite.com/ClientConfig.xsd/")
public class ClientConfig {}
```

Since you declared the namespace on the `@XmlSchema` on the `package-info` class you don't need to repeat it on the `@XmlRootElement`.

```java
package com.convertXml.docSite.XmlConverter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="ClientConfig")
public class ClientConfig {}
```

**Demo**

Now the `unmarshal` will work correctly:

```java
package com.convertXml.docSite.XmlConverter;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClientConfig.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<ClientConfig xmlns='http://www.docsite.com/ClientConfig.xsd'/>");
        ClientConfig clientConfig = (ClientConfig) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html